# Unterschied zwischen "Intelligent", "Klug" & "Schlau"

Tags: meaning, standard-german

Ich bin neu im Deutsch. In meinem Buch (Menschen B1.1), habe ich zwei Sätze mit

> Intelligent & Klug

gesehen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diese? Und was bedeutet **Schlau**? Ist es das Gleich oder nicht?

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schlau *um Wege wissend, seine Ziele (dennoch) zu erreichen*; im Gegensatz zu gebildet.

Comment: BTW, you can ask a question, and have it answered in English. I'm just mentioning it because your profile page is in English.

Comment: Es ist nicht ganz einfach, ähnlich wie im Englischen: clever, smart, intelligent, sly. Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Worten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Bedeutungen überlagern sich oft, so dass man häufig 2 oder 3 Begriffe verwenden kann.

Schläue kann aber einfach darin bestehen, dass man viel weiß und es durch Fleiß erlernt hat, ohne dass man selbst irgendetwas kreativ geschaffen hat. Ein sehr intelligenter Mensch kann bei der Reparatur eines Apparates zum Beispiel versagen, weil er das Spezialwerkzeug, mit dem es ganz leicht geht, nicht kennt. Klug wäre es dann, einen Experten zu befragen.

Klug kann man sein ohne ein breites Wissen zu haben und ohne die Fähigkeit, originelle Lösungen selbst zu entwickeln. Klugheit besteht darin, das Wissen, das man hat, in der Praxis angemessen einzusetzen. Klugheit geht ein wenig in Richtung Weisheit.

Intelligenz ist die Fähigkeit selbst eigenständig Lösungen zu entwickeln. Eine intelligente Lösung kann **nicht** sehr klug sein, weil sie Spätfolgen nicht in Betracht gezogen hat. Sie kann auch **nicht** sehr schlau sein, weil sie zu teuer ist. Intelligenz ist immer mit einem Schuss Originalität versehen.

Um in einem Wissensquiz zu gewinnen sollte man v.a. schlau sein. Als Bergführer sollte man bevorzugt eine kluge Person verpflichten. In der Forschungsabteilung möchte man am liebsten einen intelligenten Mitarbeiter haben.

Bauernschlau ist ein Bauer, der in der Lage ist, einen Städter übers Ohr zu hauen.

Comment: +1. Dennoch oder deshalb : 'eine intelligente Lösung kann nicht... ' heißt soviel wie 'eine intelligente Lösung ist nie...' . Du meinst aber eine nicht ausschließende weitere Eigenschaft. Es muss also 'muss nicht' heißen.

Comment: @planetmaker: Nein. "Eine intelligente kann (nicht sehr klug sein)" vs. "eine intelligente Lösung (kann nicht) sehr klug sein". Der Tausch des Wortes können gegen müssen ändert an der zweideutigen Struktur nichts. Probier es aus.

Comment: Die klammersetzung existiert in der Sprache so nicht. Genau deshalb muss für den Sinn in der Verneinung 'kann' gegen 'muss' getauscht werden. Bei verknüpften Ereignissen A (Verknüpfung) B gilt: Kann = manchmal. Kann nicht = nie. Muss = immer. Muss nicht = manchmal

Comment: Die von dir postulierte Mehrdeutigkeit der Aussagen existiert deshalb gar nicht.

Comment: Eine solche Klammersetzung existiert in der Sprache nicht, wohl wahr, deswegen habe ich in der Antwort auch keine benutzt. Was sehr wohl existiert, das ist eine Betonung. Ich werde versuchen, das mit Fettung hervorzuheben.

Answer (score 3):

Ich versuche diese Frage auf B1 Niveau zu beantworten.

Das Nomen zum Adjektiv intelligent ist Intelligenz. Davon abgeleitet wurde der Intelligenztest / Intelligenzquotient (IQ). Man versucht damit Intelligenz zu messen. Man kann daran erkennen, dass dies einie Eigenschaft ist, die Menschen zugeschrieben wird und von Mensch zu Mensch unterschiedlich ist.
Intelligente Menschen sind häufig in der Lage, Sachverhalte (Dinge) schneller zu verstehen, zu lernen und zu begreifen. Klug und Klugheit sind Synonyme.

Schlau wird gelegentlich auch synonym zu klug/intelligent verwendet. Oft gibt es eine "schlaue Lösung" für ein Problem. Jeder Mensch, unabhängig seiner Intelligenz, kann die schlaue Lösung verwenden (sofern er sie kennt). Ebenso können Genies einen "dummen Fehler" machen. Das Gegenteil zu schlau ist dumm. Dumm ist aber nicht das Gegenteil zu intelligent/klug.

In einem Kommentar wurde noch gebildet erwähnt. Üblicherweise lernt man im Laufe seiner Bildung die "schlauen Lösungen" für Probleme. Das sagt allerdings nichts über Intelligenz aus.

Answer (score 1):

Die kurze Antwort ist, dass diese Begriffe sehr ähnlich sind. Wenn man jemanden beschreiben möchte, kann man jedes dieser drei Worte benutzen und die Person mit der man spricht, wird verstehen was man meint.

Welches Wort man tatsächlich benutzt hängt meist vom Zusammenhang ab. Ich finde meine Kollegen haben den Unterschied sehr gut erklärt, aber ich würde gerne noch ergänzen, wann man welches Wort am Ehesten benutzt - unabhängig von der tatsächlichen Definition von Intelligenz, Schläue und Klugheit.

Intelligent ist jemand, der viel gelernt hat und daher sein Wissen hat. Er/sie weiß viel, weil er/sie sich mit dem Thema beschäftigt hat.

Klug ist jemand, der viel weiß. Woher er/sie das Wissen hat ist im Großen und Ganzen egal. Deshalb werden oft intelligente Menschen auch klug genannt.

Schlau ist jemand, der kreative Lösungen für Probleme findet. Dabei ist nicht wichtig, dass dieser Mensch besonders viel weiß oder sich mit einem Thema befasst hat.

Comment: Ich stimme mit der Definition von klug und schlau überein. Aber Intelligenz hat nix mit Wissen sondern nur mit Problemlösungsvermögen und schnellen Verständnis von Zusammenhängen zu tun. Man kann strohdumm und doch hoch intelligent sein. Du definierst als erstes 'gebildet' (und nicht intelligent)